# Advice: Generating isolated environements programatically with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, sandbox

For a personal project, I would like to test and grade (untrusted) C code.
What I had in mind was a 'manager' pod that would, for each program it has to test, generate a new pod, then send to it a git repository (the untrusted code) as well as  a tester and the expected results. The new pod would build, execute and test that code. It would then return the results to the manager pod and be deleted.
I am a beginner in k8s (mostly played with minikube), and I do not know what solutions I have to do that.

Could someone guide me to what I could use/make to do that?

Thank you!